# Does the libubox supports multithreads

Tags: c, linux, openwrt

I m working on a project using libubox. And I have remarked that libubox execute functions in sequentiel mode and not in multthread mode.

Are there some one who could confirm this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the libubox does not support multithreading

here after the justification of Felix (the Libubox developer)

> On 2012-11-07 2:59 PM, KALLEL Mohamed wrote:
>
> > Hello
> >
> > I m contributing in the development of an opensource project which use 
> >     libubox. and I remarked that libubox execute handler functions in 
> >     monothread mode and not in muItithread mode.
> >
> > 1) so I m wondering if the libubox supports execution of handler in 
> >     multi thread mode ?
> >
> > 2) if yes how to activate multithread for registred handlers with libubox
> >
> > 3) if no. I m able to create 2 threads in my main program and then each 
> >     thread will call libubox functions to register handler function. Could 
> >     you give a quick how to do it with libubox? Hi,
>
> uloop in libubox is currently not designed in a thread-safe way. I
>   would recommend running uloop in one thread only, and handing
>   processing for received events off to other threads. Would that be
>   enough for the needs of your application or do you need any specific
>   changes?
>
> I have not really looked at thread-safe use of epoll yet (which is
>   used in uloop internally), I only remember some recent kernel related
>   discussion pointing out that its threaded use may be a bit tricky
>   because of some race conditions that were only fixed recently.
>
> - Felix